# Tracking Adwords Conversions from an iFrame Widget

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-ads-api, google-tag-manager

**The Website**

[Saritias](http://www.saritas.com.au/articles/RESERVATIONS/3)

**The Situation**

My client wishes to track Google Adwords conversions. A conversion is reached when a customer clicks on an ad, arrives on the website and then books a table using the 3rd Party booking widget ([ResDiary](http://www.resdiary.com/)).

**The Problem**

The widget is within an iframe, so as I understand it, this means that the tag manager code inserted into the widget cannot see the Adwords related cookie set by Google in the parent window.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MY SOLUTION**

I created 2 accounts in the Tag Manager.

1. For the Main Site
2. One for the widget site

The widget site contained a Custom HTML tag that sent an event to the parent iframe:

```html
<script>
var topOrigin = 'http://www.saritas.com.au';
if (window.postMessage) {
  window.parent.postMessage('confirmation', topOrigin);
}
</script>
```

I set the trigger for this to fire on the desired confirmation page in the widget.

For the main site I again used a Custom HTML tag that contained an event listener that makes use of the [Google Async Conversion Library](https://developers.google.com/adwords-remarketing-tag/asynchronous/?hl=en) and fires the event when the listener is triggered.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script>
      /* <![CDATA[ */
    var google_conversion_id = 952604500;
    var google_conversion_language = "en";
    var google_conversion_format = "3";
    var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
    var google_conversion_label = "eMKnCNzU5F8Q1K6exgM";
    var google_remarketing_only = false;
    /* ]]> */
  
  function trackConv(google_conversion_id, google_conversion_label) {
        window.google_trackConversion({
   google_conversion_id: google_conversion_id, 
   google_remarketing_only: false
  });
   }
  
// Replace with your domain here.
var allowedOrigins = ['https://widget-au.resdiary.com'];
function xDomainHandler(event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  var origin = event.origin;

  // Check for the whitelist.
  var found = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < allowedOrigins.length; i++) {
    if (allowedOrigins[i] == origin) {
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!found) return;

  // Might be a different message.
  if (event.data != 'confirmation') return;
  trackConv(google_conversion_id, google_conversion_label);
}
if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener('message', xDomainHandler, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
  window.attachEvent('onmessage', xDomainHandler);
}

</script>
```

I set the trigger for this to be for the single page the the widget appears.